# Definition of differentiability using sequence notations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

> Let $f$ be differentiable at $c$ and let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences such that $a_n<c<b_n$, and $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges to $c.$ Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(a_n)-f(b_n)}{a_n-b_n}=f'(c).$$

What I have so far is that

\begin{align}
& \frac{f(a_n)-f(b_n)}{a_n-b_n}-f'(c) \\[8pt]
= {} & \left[\frac{f(b_n)-f(c)}{b_n-c}-f'(c)\right]\cdot\frac{b_n-c}{b_n-a_n} \\[8pt]
& {} + \left[\frac{f(c)-f(a_n)}{a_n-c}-f'(c)\right]\cdot\frac{c-a_n}{b_n-a_n}
\end{align}
All is left to prove is that $\frac{b_n-c}{b_n-a_n}$ and $\frac{c-a_n}{b_n-a_n}$ is bounded. Then, I am planning to use the fact that $f$ is differentiable at c to show that the brackets goes to 0 and thus the whole expression goes to 0. Thus, the equation. But I am having hard time formally proving that $\frac{b_n-c}{b_n-a_n}$ and $\frac{c-a_n}{b_n-a_n}$ is bounded. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Observe that $0<(b_n-c)/(b_n-a_n)<1$ and $0<(c-a_n)/(b_n-a_n)<1$ because $a_n<c<b_n$

Comment: @GReyes Wow... It was really obvious. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can find this, and interesting variations, on Baby Rudin, exercise 5.19.